# Modify web page content and styling using google tag manager

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I am able to modify specific web pages styling by using javascript on google tag manager.

I am planning to explore more options to modify template via google tag manager eg add new divider/content on specific location etc.

I found it convenient as compared to directly editing the template.

Is this consider bad practice or any security risk from acheieving such task via google tag manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mileage may vary, but is certainly not considered good practice (and Google directly recommends against changes to the layout via GTM).

- you store the design for you page in two separate locations (maybe okay if you are the only dev, but confusing for anyone who works on your page and cannot find the styles in the source code)
- do you do version control ? If so, how do you check in your design changes from GTM ?
- the "standard" version of GTM does not have a SLA and might break at any given moment (so you need a plan B).
- If you make changes that require a repaint there will be a performance penalty on the client side (not specific to GTM, but avoiding repaints is done more easily before the page has rendered)
- If you pull in assets (e.g. background images) from other locations you might accidentally break ssl encryption (again not specific to GTM and of course avoidable with due diligence)

So good practice, it is not. But if you are a single dev on a not-too large site there is probably no point in overthinking it, so if after my list you still feel this works for you, go ahead.